# Is the javascript linear loaded?

Tags: javascript

I mean, if the first functions declared are the first functions loaded?

Because, if so, I could add a `var loaded = true` to the end of the file to know if it is loaded (I know I can use `onload`, but I would like this alternative also).

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the browser you are using.  Depending on your requirements, you might benefit from a [script loader](http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2010/04/require-for-jquery.html).  That way you could declaratively define what scripts you wanted to load, and the loader would ensure that they are loaded once.  Also, [here](http://www.artzstudio.com/2008/07/beating-blocking-javascript-asynchronous-js/) is a little more information about javascript loading.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML standard [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.4) that the SCRIPT elements are interpreted in the order in which they are declared. That includes both inline javascript and references to external files.

Answer (score 0):

Its really worth using a framework such as jquery or [YUI](http://yui.yahoo.com) when building anything serious with javascript, but to answer your question yes, my understanding is that javascript files are executed as they are loaded.